# List Bullets not show proper in Safari

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have some type of user list. I have used list with default bullets. It's show proper in Chrome and Firefox but in Safari it's not displaying proper. I know if i remove `float:left` from `a` tag it show proper. But with `float:left` not showing proper, why? I am checking in MAC safari Version 9.0.

Here is fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yje9j1fq/1/)

```css
.user_list {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.user_list  a{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list user_list">
  <li>
    <a href="BT1672" title="Test Event" class="sl_name">
      Test Event<br>
    </a>
  </li>
  <small class="s_color sl_email">29-09-2017 12:50 PM</small>
</ul>
```

Comment: instead of float:left, you can use display:inline-block or block. It works fine.

Comment: I know if i remove `float:left` and add `display:inline-block` or not add anything it was display proper and , but i want to know why this was happing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;` in `.user_list  a`

```css
.user_list {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.user_list  a{
  display:inline-block; //add
}
```

```html
<ul class="list user_list">
  <li>
    <a href="BT1672" title="Test Event" class="sl_name">
      Test Event<br>
    </a>
  </li>
  <small class="s_color sl_email">29-09-2017 12:50 PM</small>
</ul>
```

Hope it will help

Comment: I can confirm this works, however I would also like to point out that <small> should not really be placed within a <ul> tag.